# Where is the developer documentation for Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager?

Tags: iis-7, documentation, vbscript

I am trying to manage an IIS7 website during an application installation.  I have been using WiX and PowerShell.  However I have recently come across a few postings that make me think WiX with VBScript and Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager might be a better option.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any developer documentation on WritableAdminManager.  I do not know what properties and methods are supported.  All I can find are various examples on [IIS.net](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites).

Where is the developer documentation for Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the `Application Host Administration Interfaces`, and you can find the documentation for the [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965217%28VS.90%29.aspx) on MSDN.